# How to deploy automationAccounts/python2Packages by Azure resource manager?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation

Now i want to import Python packages by ARM template.
Please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1u10.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstart-create-automation-account-template?toc=/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/toc.json) to set up an ARM template to deploy your Azure Automation account.

After setting up the ARM template:

- On your local machine, you can execute the related [**Azure CLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-cli) or [**Azure PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell) commands to run the ARM template deployment.
- In the Azure Pipelines on Azure DevOps, you can use the [**ARM Template Deployment Task**](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md) to run the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

For automation download and add python package in Azure Automation Account:

Step 1: You have to [create Azure Run As Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/create-run-as-account#create-account-in-azure-portal).

Step 2: Create Runbook and you can import a Python 3 package and its dependencies by importing the [following Python script](https://github.com/azureautomation/runbooks/blob/master/Utility/Python/import_py3package_from_pypi.py) into a Python 3 runbook, and then running it

Step 3: Start runbook
You have to add following argument for runbook:

```
subscription_id (-s) - Subscription id of the Automation account
resource_group (-g) - Resource group name of the Automation account
automation_account (-a) - Automation account name
module_name (-m) - Name of module to import from pypi.org
```

More information: [Manage python2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/python-packages), [Manage python3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/python-3-packages)

Comment: Please don't post multiple identical answers to different questions. This is considered spam.